# Why doesn't custom SwiftUI view animate on ViewModel state change?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am presenting a custom view when my viewModel changes to an error state. I want to animate this presentation. I represent the viewModel state using an enum

```
enum ViewModelState<T> {
    case idle
    case error(Error)
    case loading
    case data(T)

    var isError: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .error:
            return true
        default:
           return false
        }
    }
}
```

In my viewModel I have this property...

`@Published var state: ViewModelState = .idle`

When it changes to an error state I want to animate in my error view. When I do the following with an if statement in my view it animates in...

```
private var content: some View {
    return ZStack {
        mainView // VStack
        if case let .error(error) = viewModel.state {
            ErrorView(
                errorDescription: error.localizedDescription,
                state: $viewModel.state
            )
        }
    }.animation(.default)
}

var body: some View {
    content
    .navigationBarTitle(viewModel.title)
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
}
```

However I want to switch on the error and do this

```
private var content: some View {
    switch viewModel.state {
    case .idle:
        return mainView.eraseToAnyView()
    case let .error(error):
        return ZStack {
            mainView
            ErrorView(
               errorDescription: error.localizedDescription,
               state: $viewModel.state
            )
        }.animation(.default).eraseToAnyView()
    default:
        return EmptyView().eraseToAnyView()
    }
}
```

I don't understand why this approach doesn't animate - is there a way to animate views without resorting to multiple properties in my view model to represent state/computed properties off my state enum or is this the best approach?

Comment: Can you set the the state change within the body of `withAnimation` view modifier. Refer:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/withanimation(_:_:)

Comment: The second is much worse for SwiftUI from many points, use first, if-based, approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AnyView` hides all implementation details from the compiler. That means that SiwftUI *can't* animate, because it tries to infer all animations during compilation.

That's why you should try to avoid `AnyView` whenever possible.

If you want to seperate some logic of your `body` into a computed property (or function), use the `@ViewBuilder` annotation.

```
@ViewBuilder
private var content: some View {
    switch viewModel.state {
    case .idle:
       mainView
    case let .error(error):
       ZStack {
            mainView
            ErrorView(
               errorDescription: error.localizedDescription,
               state: $viewModel.state
            )
        }.animation(.default)
    default:
       EmptyView()
    }
}
```

Notice that I removed `return` in the property. The `@ViewBuilder` behaves much like the default `body` property by wrapping everything in a `Group`.

---

The second problem are the states between you animate.
By using the `switch` you are creating an `SwiftUI._ConditionalContent<MainView,SwiftUI.ZStack<SwiftUI.TupleView<(MainView, ErrorView)>>`

That is a little hard to parse, but you creating a `ConditionalContent` that switches between just the `MainView` and an `ZStack` consisting of your `MainView` and the `ErrorView`, which is not what we want.

We should try to create a `ZStack` with out `MainView` and an optional `ErrorView`.

What I like to to is to extend by view models with a computed `error: Error?` property.

```
extension ViewModel {
    var error: Error? {
        guard case let .error(error) = state else { 
              return nil
        }
        return error
   }
}
```

Now, you can create an optional view, by using the `map` function of the `Optional` type

```
ZStack {
    mainView
    viewModel.error.map { unwrapped in
         ErrorView(
             errorDescription: unwrapped.localizedDescription,
             state: $viewModel.state
         )
    }
}
```

That should work as expected.